# Force angular2-multiselect dropdown to open downwards

Tags: css, angular

I am using angular2-multiselect dropdown in my angular 8 application. Ie there a way to force the dropdown to always open downwards. I dont see any settings in the multiselect to handle it so can it be done using CSS.

Comment: There is option of position to open `drop-down` to `bottom` but you cant force it to open always at bottom as its the default behavior of drop-down which adjust its according to view-port/DOM position [Ref](http://cuppalabs.github.io/components/multiselectDropdown/#Themes-and-Theming)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. Setting `autoPosition: false` fixed it for me.

You can find it in `DropdownSettings` interface:
https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/blob/master/projects/angular2-multiselect-dropdown-lib/src/lib/multiselect.interface.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use ".dropdown" class. It will force the dropdown to open downwards.

Answer (score 0):

use this keyword **disableOptionCentering** as attribute  inside **mat-select** tag. this helps to open the material dropdown or multiselect dropdown in downwards.

Example: `<mat-select disableOptionCentering > </mat-select>`

Answer (score 0):

The only solution was using [CSS to control display div](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-multiselect-opendropdown-programmatically).

HTML

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
   [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)">
</angular2-multiselect>


<button (click)="openDropdown()" >
  Click Here to Open Dropdown
</button>
```

Typescript

```
import { Component,ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularMultiSelect } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown';

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  dropdownList = [];
  selectedItems = [];
  dropdownSettings = {};

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dropdownList = [
      { id: 1, itemName: "apple" },
      { id: 2, itemName: "banana" },
      { id: 3, itemName: "cherry" },
      { id: 4, itemName: "dates" },
      { id: 5, itemName: "eggfruit" },
      { id: 6, itemName: "Farkleberry" },
      { id: 7, itemName: "Guava" }
    ];
    this.dropdownSettings =
      {
        singleSelection: true,
        text: "fruits",
        enableSearchFilter: true,
        classes: "myclass custom-class",
        autoPosition: false
      };
  }
  onItemSelect(item: any) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this.dropdownList);

    this.renderer.removeStyle(this.getElementDropdown(), 'display')
  }

  openDropdown(){
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.getElementDropdown(), 'display', 'block');
  }

  private getElementDropdown(): HTMLElement{
    return document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-list")[0] as HTMLElement;
  }
}
```